# Why changed the color for all points instead of one?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, shader

I learn WebGL. I write a sample: to draw the points for each mouse click. Each of the point has own color (it depends on coordinates of the click). I expected to get the result similar of this:

[image]

But *all* my points change own color together *for each mouse click* (earch picture is the next mouse click):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why changed the color for all points instead of one?

My JavaScript code:

```
var VSHADER_SOURCE = null;
var FSHADER_SOURCE = null;
var points = []; // coordinates of each mouse click (WebGL coordinate system)

// entry point
function main(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
  if(!canvas){
    console.log('Element with the "webgl" id wasn\'t found.');
    return;
  }
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if(!gl){
    console.log('Can\'t to get the WebGL context.');
    return;
  }
  loadShaderFromFile(gl,'./shaders/vertex.shader', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  loadShaderFromFile(gl,'./shaders/fragment.shader', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}

// loading vertex or fragment shader
function loadShaderFromFile(context, fileName, shaderType){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status != 404){
      onLoadShader(context, request.responseText, shaderType);
    }    
  }
  request.open('GET', fileName, true);
  request.send();
}

function onLoadShader(context, shader_source_code, shaderType){
  var gl = context;
  if(shaderType == gl.VERTEX_SHADER){
    VSHADER_SOURCE = shader_source_code;
  }
  else if(shaderType == gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER){
    FSHADER_SOURCE = shader_source_code;
  }
  else{
    console.log('Unexpected shader type.');
    return;
  }

  // only when code sources of both shaders are gotten then continue...
  if(VSHADER_SOURCE && FSHADER_SOURCE){
      start(context);
  }
}

// initializing of the shaders and registering of the 'mousedown' event 
function start(gl){
  if(!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)){
    console.log('Can\'t initialize the shaders.');
    return;
  }

  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
  canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){
    // Attantion: I put the gl and canvas too.
    onMouseDown(ev, gl, canvas, u_FragColor);
  }  
}

// it redraws all points again for each mouse click
function onMouseDown(ev, gl, canvas, u_FragColor){  
  var x = ev.clientX;
  var y = ev.clientY;
  var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var gl_x = (x - rect.left - canvas.width / 2) / (canvas.width / 2);
  var gl_y = (canvas.height / 2 - (y - rect.top)) / (canvas.height / 2);
  points.push(gl_x);
  points.push(gl_y);
  console.log('x = ' + gl_x + '; y = ' + gl_y);  

  var a_PointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_PointSize');
  if(a_PointSize < 0){
    console.log('Can\'t to get a pointer for the "a_PointSize" variable.');
    return;
  }  
  gl.vertexAttrib1f(a_PointSize, 10.0);

  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if(a_Position < 0){
    console.log('Can\'t to get a pointer for the "a_Position" variable.');
    return;
  }

  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  for(i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2){
    var _x = points[i];
    var _y = points[i+1];

    gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_Position, _x, _y);

    // Set color of point
    if (gl_x <= 0 && gl_y >= 0){
      gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else if (gl_x > 0 && gl_y >= 0){
      gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else if (gl_x <= 0 && gl_y <= 0){
      gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
      gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

Also I see other sample (from [this book](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/)) *which does the same and works fine(!!!)*:

```
// ColoredPoint.js (c) 2012 matsuda
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
  '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'precision mediump float;\n' +
  'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' +  // uniform変数
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {
  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  // // Get the storage location of a_Position
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return;
  }

  // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
  var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
  if (!u_FragColor) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
    return;
  }

  // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press
  canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){ click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) };

  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

var g_points = [];  // The array for the position of a mouse press
var g_colors = [];  // The array to store the color of a point
function click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) {
  var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
  y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);

  // Store the coordinates to g_points array
  g_points.push([x, y]);
  // Store the coordinates to g_points array
  if (x >= 0.0 && y >= 0.0) {      // First quadrant
    g_colors.push([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]);  // Red
  } else if (x < 0.0 && y < 0.0) { // Third quadrant
    g_colors.push([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]);  // Green
  } else {                         // Others
    g_colors.push([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);  // White
  }

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  var len = g_points.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var xy = g_points[i];
    var rgba = g_colors[i];

    // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
    gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, xy[0], xy[1], 0.0);
    // Pass the color of a point to u_FragColor variable
    gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
    // Draw
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

It works fine! I doesn't understand why *my version* of code doesn't work as I expected...

Comment: This: `'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' +  // uniform変数` is not the best approach to this problem. Uniform means constant, and if you use uniforms to set the color for each vertex instead of a vertex attribute, then you have to draw each point separately. You will never get good performance doing that.

Comment: I learn WebGL through the book step by step. Attribute is not accessible in the fragment shader. My code variant doesn't use the array of colors, but author of book does it. Is it necessary for getting an expected result?

Comment: I know you _already_ draw each point separately, but a vertex attribute is a lot more sensible. The way that you send a vertex attribute to a fragment shader is to read it in the vertex shader and write to a `varying`. If you are reading a book, then it will probably teach you this later.

Comment: >You would use a varying to pass the vertex attribute into the fragment shader.< 
How can I do it right?

Comment: I know about the WebGL buffer existing (`gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` and `gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), but it will discovered in the next chapter of book. I still learn the codes of previous chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks in the comments saying that the right way to do this is with a vertex attribute and drawing all the points using one draw call are right, but since you're following a book I assume it will introduce how to do things efficiently later.

For now, let's look at your problem. Here's the trouble:

```
for(i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2){
   var _x = points[i];
   var _y = points[i+1];

   gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_Position, _x, _y);

   // Set color of point
   if (gl_x <= 0 && gl_y >= 0){
     ...
   ...
 }
```

You're not using the positions of the individual points (`_x` and `_y`) to decide the color. You're using the variables `gl_x` and `gl_y`, which were set at the top of your function by the last click point. And that's exactly what you're seeing!

Some general advice to avoid having gotten this problem: separate the event-handling from the drawing. That is, at the end of your click handler, call a separate function (let's call it `redraw()`) which goes through the data and draws all the points. This is essential in complex programs (ones that have more than one sort of input events), and in this particular case it would have caused you to get an error for using the wrong variable, since `gl_x` is defined within the click handler function but would not be in the drawing function.

Comment: Oh my God... You are right. I didn't note that used the `gl_x` and `gl_y` instead of `_x` and `_y`. Now it works fine. You gave to me a good advice. I will use it. Thank you!